# Как рисовать планарный граф?

Tags: математика, графика, графы, геометрия

Я ищу библиотеку (язык не имеет значения) для того чтобы нарисовать планарный граф. На вход подается матрица графа и заранее известно что граф планарен. На выходе я хочу получить координаты вершин графа. При этом, если провести ребра в соответствии с матрицей, то ребра не должны пересекаться.

Что я пробовал:

Graphviz (Java) - не гарантирует планарность, и в уже простейшем случае дает пересечения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

D3 (JS) - в частности force-layout simulation. Тоже самое. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: planarity в python может подойти.
[Гитхаб](https://github.com/hagberg/planarity)